# What to do when ubuntu-vm-builder completed?

Tags: xen, virtualization

I already have the VM (Xen based) installed, but the Xen config used specified "Linux kernel" as "None".

The exact command line was:

`ubuntu-vm-builder xen precise -v --debug --addpkg openssh-server`

Two images and a xen VM config was generated in /etc/xen/ubuntu-xen , I'll provide more info later , i'm at the other computer now.

How should I start the VM?

**UPDATE**

I got a xen.conf :

```
# Configuration file for the Xen instance ubuntu, created
# by VMBuilder
kernel = 'None'
ramdisk = 'None'
memory = 128

root = '/dev/xvda1 ro'
disk = [
'tap:aio:/root/ubuntu-xen/tmpZV_BzU,xvda1,w',
'tap:aio:/root/ubuntu-xen/tmpeUm7XN,xvda2,w'
]

name = 'ubuntu'

dhcp    = 'dhcp'
vif = ['']

on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'

extra = 'xencons=tty console=tty1 console=hvc0'
```

Comment: What artifacts did vmbuilder create? What options did you pass it? Did it create a script, config file, image, etc.? The more information you can provide, the more we can help.

Comment: @ToddDeshane , i got a ext3 loop image and a xen.conf , the image was not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to start the VM with:

```
xm create /path/to/xen.conf
```

Alternatively, you can decide to use other toolstacks on Ubuntu based on your needs (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed)

Comment: I get the following error: `Error: Cannot find kernel "None"`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create the PV guest with the installer as described on: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed

Alternatively, you should be able to use the image that vmbuilder created.

More info needed. (I'll post a comment and we can edit this when we figure this out)

Comment: I provided the xen.conf generated , not sure why kernel should be 'None' here